# NHibernate Linq Expression dynamic projection

Tags: nhibernate

How can i dynamically change the selected columns in the generated sql query when using a linq expression?
Its a new session for each time the query is executed.
Even when I set the MapExp as null after first creation an then changing the bool value to false, it still generates the column in the sql query.
The code runs in a wpf application.

```
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Entity, Model>> MapExp = x => new Model 
    {
        Id=xId,
        Count= LoadFormulaField ? x.Count: null,
        ...          
    };

var result = session.Query<Entity>().Select(MapExp))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the ternary-conditional as part of the expression which is causing the "Count" column to always be queried.
One option to avoid this could be:

```
var query = session.Query<Entity>();

IQueryable<Model> result = null;
if (LoadFormulaField)
{
    result = query.Select(x => new Model
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Count = x.Count,
    });
}
else
{
    result = query.Select(x => new Model
    {
        Id = x.Id,
    });
}
```

Which would get a little less ugly if you separate in a couple of methods I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But why is the expression not changed? Its a new session and new expression is created with every call from the GUI. It seems like the state of the expression is created first time still exists the second time.

Comment: Because you are not changing the expression. It is a new instance, but the expression is just the same, "Count = LoadFormulaField ? x.Count: null" is not deciding to put one or the other in the expression, the whole conditional ends up as part of the expression itself.